# Visual c++ 2012: why does priority_queue require overloading of assignment operator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to implement a A* search function in c++, and I'm having a lot of trouble with priority queues. From the examples I can find online, it seems that only a comparator class with overloaded "()" needs to be defined; however, it seems that the Visual C++ compiler wants the assignment operator "=" defined for elements of the priority queue, otherwise it generates an error message saying:

error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'node'

which points to a line within their source code which implements the `<algorithm>` library.

So I proceeded to write an overloaded "=" operation for 'node' class, only to find out that the "push" operation does an assignment at some point, so I end up with a queue of identical 'node' objects.

Am I missing something here?

Below is the relevant code

node.h

```
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
//node used in the A* search
struct node{
public:
    friend void operator<<(std::ostream& o,node& n);
    node(std::string& s):msg(s),gScore(0),hScore(0),parent(nullptr){};
    int getHeuristics( node& n);
    bool operator==(node n){return n.msg.compare(msg)?false:true;};
    node& operator=(node& n){msg = n.msg;gScore = n.gScore;hScore = n.hScore; return *this;};
    void setG(int g){gScore = g;}
    int getG(void) {return gScore;}
    int getH(void) {return hScore;}
    int getOverall(void){return hScore + gScore;}
    node* getParent(void){return parent;}
    std::string& msg;
private:
    node* parent;
    int gScore;
    int hScore;
};
```

WordLadder.c (part of it; the "comparator" just compares the nodes in a certain way):

```
    string apple("apple");
    string shite("shite");
    string germanApple("apfel");
    node germanNode(germanApple);
    node a(apple);
    node b(shite);
    a.getHeuristics(germanNode);
    b.getHeuristics(germanNode);
    priority_queue<node,vector<node>,comparitor> p;
    p.push(a);
    //cout<<b;
    p.push(b);
    cout<<b; //prints "apple"
```

Comment: The standard containers work by copying elements, so there must be an "operator =" available. I don't know why the compiler complained in your case, unless it's really smart and surmised you should define an "operator =" because of the pointer member "node* parent". Generaly speaking, when there are pointer members the default "operator =" is not semantically correct.

Comment: @JoséX. msg is a public member of the "node" class. Could you elaborate on how the standard containers work by copying elements please? It might relate to why this is happening :\ I'm curious because pushing them onto something else, like a vector<node>, doesn't seem to change the contents at all.

Comment: When you do "p.push(a)", a copy of "a" is pushed onto the container, not "a" itself. Also, forget about "msg", see my edit above.

Comment: @JoséX. I see why it insists that I have "=" overloaded now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string& msg;

msg = n.msg;
```

That's your problem right here. You need `std::string msg`, a copy, not a reference.

Comment: It solved problem indeed! Could you please explain to me what exactly happened in this example that made them identical? Thanks.

Comment: @user2531913 You cannot assign to a reference, instead you assignt to an object being referenced. As a result, when you try to swap two objects, you end up with two object that reference two identical strings. You can watch this process in your debugger. Very instructive. As a rule, avoid reference members if you plan to copy your class objects.

Comment: @user2531913: There are two differences between pointers and references, 1/ a reference cannot be null, 2/ a reference always refer to the same object. The result of (2) is that when you assign to a reference, it in facts assign to the referred-to object. To avoid shooting yourself in the foot inadvertently, the compiler will not automatically build up an assignment operator if a member is a reference; this way you can decide how assignment should be handled... and whether it was a good idea to use a reference there or not :)

Answer (score 0):

`priority_queue<...>::push` uses (effectively) the `push_heap` algorithm.  The `push_heap` algorithm requires the elements to be copy assignable.  Ergo, `priority_queue<...>::push` requires the elements to be copy assignable.

Your problem stems from storing references, which don't have proper assignment semantics.  When you assign them, it assigns the referent, it does not rebind the reference.  If you want rebindable references, then use pointers.